# "Two-way proxied" download with PHP? (one server serves file, and pings another server with client data)

Tags: php, proxy, http-headers

Sorry about the "two-way proxied download" terminology - am not sure how this would be otherwise called (correct terminology is much appreciated). Anyways:

Let's assume I have a PDF file of an article, `test.pdf` (see below for Latex example) of which I am an author, which is hosted on a conference website, and otherwise available there for free. Let's say I want to (and am allowed) to also distribute a copy of the same PDF from my website.

So, for the sake of the example, let's say:

- a local PC has a (globally resolvable) IP address 80.80.80.80
- my website server is at `myserver.com`, with IP address 90.90.90.90

  - The link to the PDF there is `http://myserver.com/dl/test.php?file=./test.pdf`
- the conference website is at `conference.org`, IP address 100.100.100.100

  - The link to the PDF there is `http://conference.org/2001/downloads/test.pdf`

What I want to do is this: when a local PC the PDF file from my website (via `http://myserver.com/dl/test.php?file=./test.pdf`), the `test.php` script should also:

- initiate a download of `http://conference.org/2001/downloads/test.pdf`, with the *original* header data of the client (that is, `conference.org` should see in their logs that it is 80.80.80.80 which requests), with my website as referrer (that is, 90.90.90.90 would be referrer); the idea of this is that the `conference.org` webhost would log the same clients that download as `myserver.com` does
- The download from `conference.org` should be terminated after 100 bytes or so, so as not to waste the bandwidth of `conference.org` -- otherwise, it is `myserver.com` that serves the PDF file
- Should the download from `conference.org` fail (e.g. if `conference.org` is temporarily offline), than that should be logged in a text file - but it should NOT otherwise interfere (as in, introduce additional delays) in the process of serving the file from `myserver.com`.

Here is an example of `test.php`, which only does the serving "from `myserver.com`"; otherwise, the relationship between files local to `myserver.com`, and their location on `conference.org`, is simulated in the `$filesRelations` array:

```php
<?php

$filesRelations = array(
  './test.pdf'   => 'http://conference.org/2001/downloads/test.pdf',
);

if(!(isset($_GET['file']))) {
  echo "<html>
  <head/>
  <body>
  <a href='?file=./test.pdf'>test.pdf</a>
  <br/> <sub>(".$filesRelations['./test.pdf'].")</sub>
  </body>
  </html>
  ";
} else {
  # echo "-- " . $_GET['file'] . " -- "; # dbg
  $localpath = $_GET['file'];
  $fdname = basename($localpath);
  $fsize = filesize($localpath);
  $includeFile = file_get_contents($localpath);

  if ($includeFile === false)
  {
    echo "Error with $localpath";
  } else {
    header("Content-type: application/pdf");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$fdname."\"");
    header("Content-length: $fsize");
    header("Cache-control: private");
    echo $includeFile;
  }
}

exit;
?>
```

How could I modify this code, so that the script "pings" the link (by initiating and terminating a short, 100-byte download) in the respective `$filesRelations` entry, *using the header data of the calling client*, before it serves the headers and the file (by echoing `$includeFile`)?

---

For testing, this is the `test.tex` file (which you can compile with `pdflatex test.tex` to obtain a `test.pdf`):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\title{Lorem Ipsum}
\author{Author's Name}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}

\lipsum[1-12]
\end{document}
```

(To test, put `test.php` and `test.pdf` in one directory, run `php-5.4.10 -S localhost:8000` in that directory, then visit `http://localhost:8000/test.php` in the web browser).

Comment: I believe the stumbling block is `the original header data of the client`.  The IP address of the client is not contained in a header, but determined by the TCP/IP layer of the socket that the client connected to.  That's what would be in the logs.  Ergo, can't be done AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @James; if not the entire "original header data", could I at least gain access to the client's IP in PHP on myserver (then I could probably somehow "fake" some header, with the client's IP inside)? EDIT: ups, just saw "TCP/IP layer" and "not contained in a header"; but I could read [`$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003145/); could I then use `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']` in the call from myserver to conference server?

Comment: `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` contains the IP address of the client connected.  You could send that data to the other server in a special request which they would read - you wouldn't be able to do this in a sneaky way though it requires the other server to implement some kind of script to receive the data.  Possibly http_x_forwarded_for, but I kind of doubt that will automatically go into the other server's logs as the client, but give it a try.

Comment: Sounds good, many thanks @James - cheers! (PS: if you want, post this as an answer, I'll accept it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the stumbling block is the original header data of the client. The IP address of the client is not contained in a header, but determined by the TCP/IP layer of the socket that the client connected to. That's what would be in the logs. So, it can't be done quite so simply.

The client's IP can be retrieved by your server via:

```
$clientIP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

If you were able to come up with a mechanism to let the other server know that this was a request on behalf of a client, you could certainly send them this data.  As you point out, perhaps try setting the `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` header in your request to that server.

Best of luck!